# How can I add onClick and onLongClick in the following code

Tags: android

It might be really simple but, I want to show all recording files on sd card and `onclick` on any of it should play, and `onlongclick` it should show options for share and delete. Currently the files appear but I am not able either play it nor `onlongclick`. 
Any help would be appreciated.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private File root;
private ArrayList<File> fileList = new ArrayList<File>();
private LinearLayout view;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    view = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.view);

    //getting SDcard root path
    root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsolutePath());
    getfile(root);

    for (int i = 0; i < fileList.size(); i++) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText(fileList.get(i).getName());
        textView.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);

        System.out.println(fileList.get(i).getName());

        if (fileList.get(i).isDirectory()) {
            textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
        }
        view.addView(textView);
    }

}

public ArrayList<File> getfile(File dir) {
    File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();
    if (listFile != null && listFile.length > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {

            if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
                fileList.add(listFile[i]);
                getfile(listFile[i]);

            } else {
                if (listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".png")
                        || listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".jpg")
                        || listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".jpeg")
                        || listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".gif"))

                {
                    fileList.add(listFile[i]);
                }
            }

        }
    }
    return fileList;
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
view.addView(textView);
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
        home.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                // your code
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Sohail, I sucessfully implemented the onClick part, but I would be greatful to you if you could also provide some more insight for the delete and share option for onLongclick.

Comment: @KunalYadav please tick mark and vote up if it helps and post an other question with your new issue and send its link to me but first try your best happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add it in your loop:

```
private File root;
private ArrayList<File> fileList = new ArrayList<File>();
private LinearLayout view;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    view = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.view);

    //getting SDcard root path
    root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsolutePath());
    getfile(root);

    for (int i = 0; i < fileList.size(); i++) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText(fileList.get(i).getName());
        textView.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);

        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                File file = fileList.get(i);
                System.out.println(file.getName() + " NORMALCLICK");
            }
        });
        textView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                File file = fileList.get(i);
                System.out.println(file.getName() + " LONGCLICK");
                return false;
            }
        });


        System.out.println(fileList.get(i).getName());

        if (fileList.get(i).isDirectory()) {
            textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
        }
        view.addView(textView);
    }

}

public ArrayList<File> getfile(File dir) {
    File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();
    if (listFile != null && listFile.length > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {

            if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
                fileList.add(listFile[i]);
                getfile(listFile[i]);

            } else {
                if (listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".png")
                        || listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".jpg")
                        || listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".jpeg")
                        || listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".gif"))

                {
                    fileList.add(listFile[i]);
                }
            }

        }
    }
    return fileList;
}
```

Comment: Thanks babadaba, I would be greatful to you if you could also provide some insight for the delete and share option for onLongclick.

Comment: Ask a new question for that. Or try to look up contextmenu and share intents for android. If my answer helped you, please upvote it if you dont mind :)

Comment: I don't have enough rep yet to upvote, both the answers are same and helped me.